# Get xml nodes using wildcard (php)

Tags: php, xml

I have xml file

```
<root>
<param1_2014>1</param1_2014>
<param2_2014>2</param2_2014>
<param2_2015>3</param2_2015>
<param2_2015>4</param2_2015>
<param3_2015>5</param3_2015>
</root>
```

How I can get all nodes, which contains "2015" substring in tags? I can't search it in manual.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The xpath function `contains` is what you're after, just check the element names against your string.

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
<param1_2014>1</param1_2014>
<param2_2014>2</param2_2014>
<param2_2015>3</param2_2015>
<param2_2015>4</param2_2015>
<param3_2015>5</param3_2015>
</root>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//*[contains(local-name(),'2015')]") as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
<param2_2015>3</param2_2015>
<param2_2015>4</param2_2015>
<param3_2015>5</param3_2015>
```

---

If you want to limit it specifically to tags *ending* in "2015" it's a little more work. Sadly xpath 2 isn't supported or the xpath function `ends-with` would be perfect here, so you'll have to make do with `substring`.

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$search = "2015";
$query = "//*[
    substring(
        local-name(),
        string-length(local-name()) - string-length('$search') + 1
    ) = '$search'
]";

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXML($node), "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
<param2_2015>3</param2_2015>
<param2_2015>4</param2_2015>
<param3_2015>5</param3_2015>
```

Comment: It's fine! Thank you!